# Issue image mapping with magento1.9 bulk product upload in csv format

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import, product-images, importexport

I had prepared the magento bulk product upload format in csv file and tested it. It's working fine, no issue in that. But, when i am uploading more than one product in the file 1st product image get mapped, after that other product images not mapped.

It's working for only one product, please review with my import file. 
[Magento import file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwmott3xwf7r38j/magento-import.csv?dl=0)
I am using default product import under "import/export".

Thanks

Comment: try to check system log it may be show you some error message